# Does two-handing a weapon affect stealth in Elden Ring?

Tags: elden-ring

I use an Uchigatana and a shield usually. When I approach an enemy that has its back towards me, naturally they notice me unless I'm crouched.

However, I noticed that when I two-hand the Uchigatana and approach the similar enemy from behind, they don't notice me regardless if I'm crouched or not.

I'm not removing the shield from my equipment, I'm just switching to two-handing the Uchigatana so that rules out the overall weight capacity affecting it.

So basically, my question is, why does this happen? Does two-handing a weapon as opposed to shield + weapon affect the stealth in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Needs verification because I'm not looking at game files, but likely one of two things is happening here.

Either:

- two-handing the weapon does count as putting the shield away and, having fewer items equipped, makes you less noticeable; or
- two-handing the weapon increases your strength by 1.5 for that weapon which might affect some unknown handling value, making it easier to go unnoticed.